# I can't purchase furnishings at my lakeview manor, says I don't have enough gold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to get my Lakeview Manor furnished, but my steward keeps saying I don't have enough gold to do so. I have 1.097.937 gold and it only costs 1.000: can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug, I've experienced this too.

There is no known way to fix this except to finish the room yourself. Also just as a heads up, getting your house carl to furnish all of the rooms for you takes a very long time

*"Purchasing furnishings from a steward will sometimes trigger them to say "You can't afford that," even though enough gold is on hand. This can also occur when remodeling a small home into an entryway before hiring a steward, at which time the furnishings for the entryway cannot be bought. There is no known fix for this bug yet."*

---

Source: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Steward_(Hearthfire)